# Ordering the output using gulp and main-bower-files (gulp-order doesn't work)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, gulp, bower

Java engineer here, new to the Javascript world, so apologies if I'm not providing enough/correct info!

I have a gulp build script and use bower to manage the dependencies for my JS frontend app. I am struggling to get the (bower controlled) vendor javascript libraries concatenated in the right order so that jQuery and angular come first.

If they aren't first then I get *angular is undefined* or *jQuery is undefined* when I load my application, as their corresponding javascript code is buried somewhere further down in the concatenated library.

I've attempted to use `gulp-order` to order the output from the resulting `main-bower-files` call, but it appears to have no effect.

My gulp task is as follows:

```
gulp.task('lib', function () {
    var files =
      gulp.src(mainBowerFiles({
        paths: {
          bowerrc: './.bowerrc',
          bowerJson: './bower.json'
        }, env: 'lib'}))
      .pipe(order(["vendor/bower/jquery/**/*.js", "vendor/bower/angular/**/*.js", "vendor/bower/**/*.js" ]))

  return processJsFiles('lib', files);
});
```

processJsFiles does the uglify work and looks pretty much like:

```
        .pipe(uglify(name + '.js', {
            outSourceMap: true,
            screwIe8: true,
            compress: {
              hoist_funs: false,
              if_return: false
            }
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(build_dir))
        .pipe(gzip())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(build_dir));
```

Any clues or better ways I should be doing this?

Answer (score 5):

After much spelunking through the docs I figured out that you need to specify the base of where the order plugin needs to start from, e.g.:

```
gulp.task('lib', function () {
    var files =
      gulp.src(mainBowerFiles({
        paths: {
          bowerrc: './.bowerrc',
          bowerJson: './bower.json'
        }, env: 'lib'}))
      .pipe(order([
          "vendor/bower/jquery/**/*.js", 
          "vendor/bower/angular/**/*.js", 
          "vendor/bower/**/*.js" 
          ], { base: './' })
      );

  return processJsFiles('lib', files);
});
```

Comment: Hi, I need to specify the order as well, but I don't quite understand your example...can you please paste here the link to the documentation? 
Thanks

Comment: The docs are linked from here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-order